# How to add am/pm to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application, I have a the following fields:
datepicker, hours dropdown, minutes dropdown, and am/pm dropdown.

In my controller I am trying to tie these fields together and create a DateTime value like this (5/18/2012 2:45 PM):

```
var datex = new DateTime(model.Scheduled.Value.Year, model.Scheduled.Value.Month, model.Scheduled.Value.Day, model.ScheduledHour, model.ScheduledMinute, 0);
```

In the above, how do I include the AM/PM value that the user selected on the UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
model.ScheduledHour + (model.AmPm == "AM" ? 0 : 12);
```